# Computation of integrals with Airy function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Let $\mathrm{Ai}$ denote the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Is it possible to compute explicitly (or bound)
$$
\int_0^{K} \frac{\mathrm{Ai}(z)}{\mathrm{Ai}(-z)} dz
$$
for $K >0$ (or also for $K = \infty$)?

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Comment: This integral has a reciprocal of a special function. Why would this integral have a closed form? Also, the integrand has discontinuities at Ai’s zeros